# How to change the b-input date type format?

Tags: bootstrap-4, vue-component

I'm using `bootstrap-vue b-input` with `type='date'`, default date format is showing dd/MM/yyyy.  How can i change it to dd-MM-yyyy?

```
<b-form-group :invalid-feedback="errors.first('birth_date')"
                  :state="!errors.has('birth_date')"
                  class="col-sm-4"
                  label="Birth Date"
                  label-for="new-employer-owner-birth-date">
      <b-input :state="!errors.has('birth_date')"
               id="new-employer-owner-birth-date"
               name="birth_date"
               type="date"
               v-model="newOwner.birth_date"
               v-validate.disable="validation.birth_date">
      </b-input>
    </b-form-group>
```

I have added `:formatter="formatDate`" after `'type'` property but it's not working either.

Answer (score 0):

> newOwner.birth_date should have a format of YYYY-MM-DD

If you are using moment(), you format your date like

```
const unformattedDate = yourDate;

newOwner.birth_date = moment(unformattedDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```